# Docker stuck at "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Note that there are two different questions in StackOverflow about the same error message but none of them seems related to the same issue I am experiencing: i.e. the fact that they have the same error message does not mean they are asking the same question. By the way none of them has an answer by now.

So I am trying to run a docker container. I issue this command:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:8.0
```

As you can see from the command itself, this is the mysql repository available in docker hub. I tried with multiple tags from 5.2 up to 8.0 and get the same error message:

```
/bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied
```

```
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
```

OS is Ubuntu Desktop 20.04

What I tried and did not work:

- I overrode the image and gave permissions to that script issuing `RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`
- I overrode the image and gave permissions to that script issuing `RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh`
- I used the parameter `--privileges`
- I made user my `docker` user in Linux has root privileges just to double check this is not the issue.
- I tried to add the flag `--security-opt apparmor=unconfined`
- I tried to add the flag `--mount 'type=volume,src=tatata,dst=/var/lib/mysql'` with a previously created volume named `tatata`

I ran other random docker containers and seem to work.

Also I inspected the dockerfile of the image, as well as the script `entrypoint.sh` itself which are available here: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/tree/mysql-server/8.0

I do not immediately know what's wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which docker version you are using?

Comment: It's in the question

Comment: Try `docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -it /bin/bash` and then inside that try to debug by running `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` and also see if you can find something fishy

Comment: Good idea. But when I run the command you mentioned, I get the same error.

Comment: Try with `/bin/sh` then

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what was the problem, but I removed docker completely using synaptic, install it again. Now everything is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, helped me after 5 hours of debuging...